# Creating a token order book without costing gas

Tags: tokens, gas, exchanges, erc-721

I'm building a DApp for ERC721 collectibles. I want to make it more like rarepepewallet.com than CryptoKitties:

1. RarePepeWallet has an order book for each token, matching asks with bids, just like any ol' exchange.
2. CryptoKitties does not; you can't place buy orders under a set sale price. Only a 'Buy Now' option.

So for my DApp, if I end up storing the order book data on the blockchain, it might cost gas for every order placed, even if it doesn't end up a successful ask/bid.

What are some ways I can circumvent this? Is 0x a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any transaction submitted and picked up by the miners will incur gas costs. 
State changes increase this gas cost.

To not incur gas costs you'd have to implement a solution offchain.